# How can drop database with a cyrillic symbol in the name?

Tags: mysql, cyrillic, drop

I have two databases in `/var/lib/mysql/:`

```
test_@x0m
test_cm
```

The database `test_@x0m` has the cyrillic symbol in the name.

In mysql this databases look like:

```
test_?m
test_cm
```

I want to remove database with the cyrillic symbol. I use commands:

```
drop database `test_@x0m`;
drop database `test_?m`;
drop database `test_\?m`;
```

But get result:

```
Unknown database
```

How can i drop database with the cyrillic symbol.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you can use a graphic sql tool for accessing your DBMS like PHPMyAdmin or SQuirrel and then issue your delete command via point and click?

Comment: MYsql Workbench has also no problem with your command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to set the correct encoding when connecting to mysql.
First of all check the default encoding variables:

```
mysql> show variables like '%character%';
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                               |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                              |
| character_set_connection | latin1                              |
| character_set_database   | latin1                              |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                              |
| character_set_results    | latin1                              |
| character_set_server     | latin1                              |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/percona-server/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

If you see something like that then you need to switch your session settings to UTF8

```
mysql> SET NAMES utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

And now you can delete the database with any utf character by simply entering it into mysql console